# how to rename project name in Adobe Premiere

Tags: adobe-premiere

Adobe Premiere[image: Adobe Premiere]
Stack overflow development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Exchange!

Typically, content about Premiere is better placed in the Video Production Stack Exchange.

To answer your question, I'd recommend the easiest way to change the project name is to do a simple File > Save As and type whatever new filename you want for the project. The shortcut is Ctrl + Shift + S.